# Why does Flatpak not require a password?

Tags: sudo, flatpak

Flatpack is installing software, right?

Example: my distro (Ubuntu based) installed Brave and Chrome browser updates today, no password was required.

Isn't `sudo`, or otherwise admin access, required to make system changes?

Comment: Does flatpak install the "sandboxed apps" globally or per-user?

Comment: I don't know. I'm the only user on this computer.

Comment: well, where are Brave and Chrome installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The per-user data is located under `$HOME/.local/share/flatpak/`, it doesn't require `sudo`. From [the reasons to use Flatpak](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/introduction.html#reasons-to-use-flatpak) is the rootless install:

> **Rootless install**: elevated privileges are not required when installing a Flatpak application or a runtime.